# R: Split a graph into several graphs

Tags: r, igraph

This graph contains 4 communities.

[image: This graph]

I want to convert each community to a new graph.
How should I do this?

Comment: providing code would be a start :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you do not provide data, I will use a simplified version of your graph to illustrate.

```
## Example graph
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_literal(1-2-3-4-1, 2-5-4,
    2-6, 6-7-10-8-6, 6-9-10)
CL = cluster_louvain(g) 
plot(CL, g)
```

[image: Communities]

In order to graph the individual communities,  you can use `induced_subgraph` to get the subgraphs and then use the like any other graph, including plotting them.

```
## Get graphs for each community
C1 = induced_subgraph(g, which(membership(CL) == 1))
C2 = induced_subgraph(g, which(membership(CL) == 2))

plot(C1)
plot(C2)
```

Note: I combined the graphs by hand. They were printed separately.

[image: Communities]